# How to dynamically set an object's method at runtime (when the object is an instance of a Gym environment)?

Tags: python, reinforcement-learning, python-3.8, monkeypatching, openai-gym

I want to override an instance's method. Let's call this instance/object `env`. The instance method has a method with the signature `f(self, other_parameter)`, which is actually not publically accessible (not sure why, but you will see below that it's not listed in the list of properties of the class and object: can you please tell me why?). However, I'm given functions of the form `new_f(other_parameter)`, i.e. without the `self` parameter, which I need to bind to the instance/object, according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/972/3924118). However, this is not my first problem.

My first problem is that no method that I've tried from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/972/3924118) seems to work in my case, i.e. the new method is not assigned to the object: at least, this is what I deduce from the fact that the method doesn't seem to be called. You can run the following example to see the problem.

```
import types
from pprint import pprint

import gym


class MyEnv(gym.Env):
    def f(self, other_parameter):
        print("other_parameter (original) =", other_parameter)
        return 0

    def step(self, action: int) -> tuple:
        return [], self.f(action), False, {}

    def reset(self):
        return []


env_id = "my_env-v1"
env = MyEnv()
gym.envs.register(id=env_id,
                  entry_point=lambda: env,
                  max_episode_steps=200)

env = gym.make(env_id)

pprint(dir(env))

env.reset()

# CORRECTLY prints the following
# other_parameter (original) = 0
# ([], 0, False, {})
print(env.step(0))

print("-" * 10)


def f(self, other_parameter):
    print("other_parameter (new) =", other_parameter)
    return 10


# IT DOES NOT SEEM TO TAKE ANY EFFECT.
# env.f = f

# EVEN IF I TRY OTHER METHODS, IT DOES NOT SEEM TO WORK.
env.f = types.MethodType(f, env)

# INCORRECTLY prints the following
# other_parameter (original) = 7
# ([], 0, False, {})
# IT SHOULD PRINT
# other_parameter (new) = 7
# ([], 10, False, {})
print(env.step(7))
```

I'm using `gym 0.17.3` (just do `pip install gym==0.17.3` to install it).

This problem probably occurs because Gym environments are created by calling `gym.make(env_id)`, which probably does some magic or weird tricks. I've already looked at [this module](https://github.com/openai/gym/blob/master/gym/envs/registration.py) where `make` is defined, but I'm not yet sure where the problem could be. I really need to set the method of a created environment once it's been created, so if you have a suggestion of how to do it, I would appreciate it.

Comment: I've just noticed that if I try to bind the new method `f` to `env` before the line `gym.envs.register(...)`, it works, but I would like to change `f` after the registration.

Answer (score 0):

I've just noticed that if I try to bind the new method `f` to `env` **before** the line `gym.envs.register(...)`, it works, but I would like to change `f` after the registration.

Meanwhile, I've also noticed that gym can wrap your environment object into another class. In the example above, it turns out that an `MyEnv` object is created inside an `TimeLimit` object, which is what `env` variable in the example above points to. I also notice that `env` has another property called `env`, which is the actual object of type `MyEnv`, so my example above works by only changing the line

```
env.f = types.MethodType(f, env)
```

to

```
env.env.f = types.MethodType(f, env)
```

This also explains why **before** registering the environment it works, because `env` before registering the environment is actually an instance of `MyEnv`.